# Simulate CPU register?

Tags: c++, cpu-registers

I want to simulate the work on register, I declare the Register class as follow

```
class Register{
    uint8_t reg_ax[2];
    Register(){
        reg_ax[0] = reg_ax[1] = 0;
    }
    uint16_t &ax(){ return (uint16_t &)reg_ax[0]; }
};
```

now I can print and edit the value of `ax` (which is 16 bits) like this:

```
Register regs;
cout << regs.ax() << endl;
regs.ax() = 5;
cout << regs.ax() << endl;
```

It works good, but now if I want to print and edit `al` & `ah` the low and high part (which are 8 bits) of `ax` what should I do ?!
I tried this, but its not working !

```
uint8_t &al(){ return reg_ax[1]; }
uint8_t &ah(){ return reg_ax[0]; }
```

now doing this will not show any output :

```
cout << regs.al() << endl;
```

Any help ?

Comment: What is not working? Any error-messages?

Comment: Does that REALLY work?

Comment: no error & compilation, but do `cout << res.al() << endl;` prints nothing !

Comment: Oh, that's long time ago. search for code in uC domain you'll find a ready solution. If you want to do it yourself, learn about unions and : as -bit number restriction in variable definitions, e.g. unsigned char B1:1; means B1 has only one bit. Using structs, unions and : you'll be able to access any bit, nibble, byte of your 16-Bit register. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is that you are trying to print an `unsigned char` as a `unsigned char`, and thus the `cout << regs.ah();` prints the character zero or some such?

This works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

class Register{
    uint8_t reg_ax[2];
public:
    Register(){
        reg_ax[0] = reg_ax[1] = 0;
    }
    uint16_t &ax(){ return (uint16_t &)reg_ax[0]; }
    uint8_t &al(){ return reg_ax[1]; }
    uint8_t &ah(){ return reg_ax[0]; }
};


int main()
{
    Register regs;
    regs.ax() = 500;
    cout << regs.ax() << endl;
    cout << (int)regs.ah() << endl;
    cout << (int)regs.al() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm posting a complete example, just like you SHOULD have done. You can then see the includes you have and whatever else I had to guess is right compared to your code.

Comment: Your `ax()` method should explicity construct a 16-bit integer using two bytes rather than relying on casting.  Casting will order the bytes in the endianess of the platform executing the program which may not be the same endianess as the simulated CPU.

Comment: -1: Sorry, It is not the way one defines register access structures in hardware-oriented domain. (see the link in to SO-answer my post) I imagine, how ugly the setters will be.  Secondly, if casting in C++, why not using C++-style casts? Casting reference to int? That should work?

Comment: Well, I can hardly cast it to a reference, since that would entirely ruin the meaning of it. I guess I could have stored the value in a temporary variable. I didn't suggest that "the above code is perfect" - just that it solves the particular problem that the original post was about. I'm absolutely sure this is not how I would write this sort of code!

Answer (score 1):

Using arrays for implementing low/high byte or 16-Bit register is not the best idea.
As I've written in comment, lear about union, : in context of variable definition, data-alignment in memory.

This should give you an idea hot to implement the convenient register access struct/class:
[Using nibbles (4 bits variables) in windows C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863575/using-nibbles-4-bits-variables-in-windows-c-c)

and don't forget to use attribute__((__packed)) of whatever is similar for your platform.

**Edited:** 
I might lose points for this but it could be usefull for you :-). Once I've implemented a tool for accessing register (memory mapped) in any manner, bitwise, nibblewise, etc. It could give you an idea of using `std::bitset`. The code is here: https://code.google.com/p/jeeamtee/wiki/Main